# PowerApps export to Excel opens blank file, but shows correctly when opened via SharePoint

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

We run an instant flow from power apps that exports items to excel. When the file opens it shows as blank/no data. Sometimes if you wait a while the data will populate. If you go open the file from the library it is saved in on SharePoint - the data shows as expected.

This process worked without issue previously, and nothing has been changed.  Not finding anyone with similar issues, but I'm hoping someone here can help.

Thanks